# File globbing and matching numbers only

Tags: bash, design-patterns, glob

In a bash script I need to verify that the user inputs actual numbers so I have thought the easiest way to make myself sure about that is implementing a `case`:

```
case $1 in
    [0-9]*)
    echo "It's ok"
    ;;
    *)
    echo "Ain't good!"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

But I'm having hard time with file globbing because I can't find a way to demand the $1 value has to be numeric only. Or another way could be excluding all the alternatives:

```
case $1 in
    -*)
    echo "Can't be negative"
    exit 1
    ;;
    +*)
    echo "Must be unsigned"
    exit 1
    ;;
    *[a-zA-z]*)
    echo "Can't contain letters"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

The thing is in this case I should be able to block "special" chars like ! ? ^ = ( ) and so forth... I don't know how to acheive it. Please anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you find a non-numeric character anywhere in the string, the input is bad, otherwise it's good:

```
case "$1" in
  *[^0-9]*) echo "first parameter must contain numbers only"; exit 1;;
esac
```

Answer (score 7):

Actually it would be better to use

```
*[!0-9]*
```

instead of

```
*[^0-9]*
```

as the first one is POSIX and the second one is a bashism[1].

[1] http://rgeissert.blogspot.com/2013/02/a-bashism-week-negative-matches.html